# Pine Script V4 Start&EndDate

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I need some help with pine script V4 code. The code works except for startDate and endDate. The date is always the same from now to beginning of may 2023 but not further.

Thanks in advance. Here´s the code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("LongSell", overlay=true)

startDate = timestamp("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z")
endDate = timestamp("2023-05-31T23:59:59Z")

rsiValue5m = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", rsi(close, 1))
rsiValue1m = security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", rsi(close, 1))

buySignal = rsiValue5m > 80 and rsiValue1m > 80 and time >= startDate and time <= endDate
sellSignal = rsiValue5m < 80 and rsiValue1m < 80 and time >= startDate and time <= endDate

strategy.entry("Compra", strategy.long, when=buySignal)
strategy.entry("Venta", strategy.short, when=sellSignal)

strategy.close("Compra", when=rsiValue1m < 80)
strategy.close("Venta", when=rsiValue1m > 80)
```

Comment: You are unable to modify the timestamp or what?

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_timestamp this is reference for the `timestamp()` function, you can edit your code accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I saw the reference for the timestamp and I tried to delete time and use only year, month and day but doesn´t work. 

For example, I want to backtest from 2020-01-01 to actual date but it only takes from 2023-05-08 to actual date and I don´t know why.

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript you can backtest up to 10 000 bars back.
So if you are on a 1 minute timeframe, you will be able to backtest to 10 000 minutes back... less than 7 days back.
Perhaps are you on a 3 minutes timeframes, which allows you to backtest approximately 20 days back ?

> That's a pinescript limit, nobody, no subscription level can afford
> more bars.

You can test the Deep Backtest from pinescript to backtest more bars back, but it will only show you results in the strategy panel, nothing on the chart.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Finally I could test using alt+g. I didn´t know about Deep Backtest as I don´t see the option in Strategy Tester. Maybe because I use Pro+.